# How to use PKCS#11 CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP mechanism in Java?

Tags: java, pkcs#11, jce, iaik-jce, sunpkcs11

I'm working with some PKCS#11 tokens that insist on using `CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP` for unwrapping AES-encrypted keys. On these tokens, `CKM_AES_CBC` and friends don't support unwrap.

At the other end of this system, I therefore need to wrap a key using a PKCS#11 token accessed via Java.

[SunPKCS11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-D3EF9023-7DDC-435D-9186-D2FD05674777) doesn't appear to support `CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP`. [Neither does IAIK](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/iaik/pkcs/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11Constants.html), as far as I can tell. Does anyone have any suggestions for achieving this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

`CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP` is rather simple mechanism so you don't need your PKCS#11 wrapper library to provide nice constants or enum members to use it.

You should be fine as long as your PKCS#11 wrapper library allows you to specify wrapping mechanim as `ulong` and its parameters as `byte[]`. SunPKCS11 is quite limited so I would try with IAIK first.

Following code sample demonstrates the idea with [Pkcs11Interop](https://pkcs11interop.net) wrapper for .NET:

```csharp
// Acquire handle to keys
ObjectHandle wrappingKey = new ObjectHandle();
ObjectHandle toBeWrappedKey = new ObjectHandle();

// Define mechanism yourself
ulong CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP = 0x00002109;
byte[] CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP_PARAM = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 };
Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP, CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP_PARAM);

// Perform wrapping
byte[] wrappedKey = session.WrapKey(mechanism, wrappingKey, toBeWrappedKey);
```

Comment: Good idea, I'll give this a go.